# Locally finite measures on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A measure $μ : B_{\mathbb{R}}→ [0,∞]$ is locally finite if $μ(K) < ∞$ for
all K compact. Show that any locally finite measure is σ-finite. Give an
example of a σ-finite measure on R, which is not locally finite.

Attempt: Since $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}[n,n+1]$ and each $[n,n+1]$ is compact, we have $\mu([n,n+1])<\infty$ for each $n$ and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. Is this part of the problem correct?

For the second part, I have no idea. I wanted to take counting measure on a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but I know this measure is locally finite on the integers and not so with the usual topology. But I know this measure is not sigma finite on $\mathbb{R}$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution to the first part is correct.
For the second part, e.g. $\mu(X) = m(\tan(X\cap(-\pi/2, \pi/2)))$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

The intuition is clear: We ignore any part of $X$ outside $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, and since $\tan$ is a bijection from $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ to $\mathbb R$, the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ induces a natural measure on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. To formally prove this won't be hard. In particular, $\mu([\pi/2, \pi/2]) = \infty$, so $\mu$ is not locally finite.

If this is not intuitive enough. We can do the following modified version of the counting measure, let $A=\{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \cdots \}$, and define $\mu(X) = |A\cap X|$, then $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite but not locally finite as $\mu([0, 1]) = \infty$.

Comment: I just accepted because he seems good, and I such dick at math so who knows.

Comment: @Nicky I provide another solution which might be easier. Mathematics is all about trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

No, your answer to 1. is not completely correct. For $\sigma$-additivity, you are in need of **disjoint** sets, i. e. consider $(n, n+1]$ (with parenthesis). These sets are not compact themselves, but are subsets of compact sets $[n, n+1]$. Now, since $\mu{}((n, n+1]) \leq \mu{}([n, n+1])$, you get the result by an inequality.
EDIT: I am wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the sets have to be disjoint? Because in my book (Folland) the definition is there exists a collection $\{E_j\}$ of $X$ such that $X= \cup E_j$ and $\mu(E_j)<\infty$ for each $j$.

Comment: You are right. Instead of showing $mu(E_j) < \infty$, I somehow came up with _using_ this fact to show $\mu(\mathbb{R}) = \infty$. (wrong proof direction) Excuse me.